# Inject javascript into every page only when the user has enabled so

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that removes ads from pages. Here is my code:

The `manifest.json`:

```
{
   "manifest_version":2,
   "name":"Ad Killer",
   "description":"A Basic program for blocking ads",
   "version":"0.5",
   "permissions": ["activeTab"],
   "background":{
      "scripts":[
      "background.js"]
   },
   "content_scripts":[
      {
         "matches":[
            "<all_urls>"
         ],
         "js":[
            "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"

         ]
      }
   ],
   "applications":{
      "gecko":{
         "id":"{99f660be-10c4-4cc8-9205-72dd45f156b9}"
      }
   },
   "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"ad128.png",
      "default_title":"Ad Killer"
   }
}
```

My `background.js`:

```
var enable = false;
enable = enable ? false : true;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    enable = enable ? false : true;
    if(enable){
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'ON' });
    //location.reload();
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); 
} else {
    enable = false;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'OFF' });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"location.reload(false);"});
    }
});
```

And finally, my `content.js`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var ob2 = $("div[class^='OB_AR_'],div[id*='OB_AR_']");
var ob3 = $("div[id^='outbrain_widget_13'],div[id*='outbrain_']");
var elems2 =  $("div[id^='taboola-'],div[id*=' taboola-']");
var elems3 =  $("div[id^='hireme'],div[id*='hireme']");
var elems4 =  $("div[id^='yandex'],div[id*='yandex']");
var banner = $("div[id^='rc-'],div[id*='rc-']");
var makeSure = $("div[id^='ad'],div[id*='ad']");
var fkn = $("div[class^='OUTBRAIN'],div[class*='outbrain']");
var yandex1 = $("div[id^='Ya_'],div[id*='ya']");
var ob11 = $("div[id^='adzerk'],div[id*='adzerk']");
var ob4 = $("div[class^='str-adunit str-adunit-mid-article str-card-exp str-collapsed clickout'],div[class*='str-adunit str-adunit-mid-article str-card-exp str-collapsed clickout']");
var trendTags = $("div[class^='trendingTags span-12'],div[class*='trendingTags span-12']");
var bank = $("div[class^='post postFill post-http://www.thejournal.ie/switching-banks-questions-department-of-finance-3355404-Apr2017/'],div[class*='post postFill post-http://www.thejournal.ie/switching-banks-questions-department-of-finance-3355404-Apr2017/']");
var google_ads = $("div[id^='google_ads_iframe_'],div[id*='google_ads_iframe_']");
var tennis1 = $("div[id^='ads'],div[id*='ads']");
var macaron = $("td[class^='marconi'],td[class*='marconi']");
var adidas = $("div[class^='GoogleActiveViewClass'],div[class*='GoogleActiveViewClass']");
var tel = $("div[class^='left-col'],div[class*='left-col']");
var aside = $("section[class^='zn zn-sponsored-outbrain-3 zn-balanced zn--idx-2 zn--ordinary zn-has-two-containers'],section[class^='zn zn-sponsored-outbrain-3 zn-balanced zn--idx-2 zn--ordinary zn-has-two-containers'");
var rh = document.getElementsByTagName("aside");
var adContent = $("div[id^='ad_'], iframe[id*='ad'");

function hideIframes() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes3() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems3.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems3[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes4() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems4.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems4[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideBanner() {
     for (var i = 0, max = banner.length; i < max; i++) {
        banner[i].hidden = true;
    };
}
function makeSure1() {
     for (var i = 0, max = makeSure.length; i < max; i++) {
        makeSure[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideFKN() {
     for (var i = 0, max = fkn.length; i < max; i++) {
        fkn[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideYandex() {
     for (var i = 0, max = yandex1.length; i < max; i++) {
        yandex1[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideOB1() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob11.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob11[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideOB2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob2.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob2[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideOB3() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob3.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob3[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideOB4() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob4.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob4[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTTags() {
     for (var i = 0, max = trendTags.length; i < max; i++) {
        trendTags[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideBank() {
     for (var i = 0, max = bank.length; i < max; i++) {
        bank[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideGAds() {
     for (var i = 0, max = google_ads.length; i < max; i++) {
        google_ads[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTennis() {
     for (var i = 0, max = tennis1.length; i < max; i++) {
        tennis1[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideMacaron() {
     for (var i = 0, max = macaron.length; i < max; i++) {
        macaron[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAdidas() {
     for (var i = 0, max = adidas.length; i < max; i++) {
        adidas[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTel() {
     for (var i = 0, max = tel.length; i < max; i++) {
        tel[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideRH() {
     for (var i = 0, max = rh.length; i < max; i++) {
        rh[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAside() {
     for (var i = 0, max = aside.length; i < max; i++) {
        aside[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideG2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = google_ads2.length; i < max; i++) {
        google_ads2[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAdContent() {
     for (var i = 0, max = adContent.length; i < max; i++) {
        adContent[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    hideIframes();
    hideOB2();
    hideIframes2();
    hideIframes3();
    hideIframes4();
    hideBanner();
    makeSure1();
    hideFKN();
    hideYandex();
    hideOB1();
    hideOB4();
    hideTTags();
    hideBank();
    hideGAds();
    hideTennis();
    hideMacaron();
    hideAdidas();
    hideTel();
    hideRH();
    hideAside();
    hideAdContent();
});

window.onload = function() {
     hideIframes();
     hideOB2();
     hideIframes2();
     hideIframes3();
     hideIframes4();
     hideBanner();
     makeSure1();
     hideFKN();
     hideYandex();
     hideOB1();
     hideOB4();
     hideTTags();
     hideBank();
     hideGAds();
     hideTennis();
     hideMacaron();
     hideAdidas();
     hideTel();
     hideRH();
     hideAside();
     hideAdContent();
};

$(window).on('load', function() {
    hideIframes();
    hideOB2();
    hideIframes2();
    hideIframes3();
    hideIframes4();
    hideIframes();
    hideBanner();
    makeSure1();
    hideFKN();
    hideYandex();
    hideOB1();
    hideOB4();
    hideTTags();
    hideBank();
    hideGAds();
    hideTennis();
    hideMacaron();
    hideAdidas();
    hideTel();
    hideRH();
    hideAside();
    hideAdContent();

});

do {
    setTimeout(hideIframes, 3000); 
}
while (elems > 0);

if (elems > 0) {
    setTimeout(hideIframes, 3000); 
}

do {
    setTimeout(hideIframes3, 3000); 
    hideIframes3();
}
while (elems3 > 0);

do {
    hideOB1();
}

while (ob11 > 0);

hideRH();
```

So here is my problem: Bascially, when the user clicks the icon, it shows a badge saying on and removes the ads for every page visited by the user *until* the user clicks the icon again to turn it off. The problem is that if I turn it on and go on to another page, the ads are showing. Is there a way so that the script is injected into every page when the user clicks the icon to turn it on? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you put these lines `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'ON' });
    //location.reload();
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); ` in a function  And call the function on the background page load ?

Comment: Obviously you need to get a list of open tabs via chrome.tabs.query. Look for examples.

Comment: @AneesIjaz thanks for the answer but I am not very good at javascript so could you provide your suggestion in an answer?

Comment: *Please* don't load jQuery into **every** page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **need** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. What of those of us who have 100's of tabs open? While it's possible you really *need* to load jQuery, it's more likely that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not using vanilla JavaScript. If that's the case (we have no way to know), doing so is a *very* poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: From what you've shown, you could very easily remove your use of jQuery by changing all of your `$('foo')` to `document.querySelectorAll('foo');`. Your use of `$(document).ready()` can also be easily converted to vanilla JavaScript. You should not be using `window.onload`, as it has the potential to generate conflicts.